# Is $\mathbb Z_p\times\mathbb Z$ isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_q\times\mathbb Z$, where $p,q$ are distinct primes

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

My question:

> Is $\mathbb Z_p\times\mathbb Z$ isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_q\times\mathbb Z$, where $p,q$ are distinct primes?

It seems they are not, but cannot take a counterexample.

Answer (score 4):

Hints:

What is the order of $\,(1,0)\in\Bbb Z_r\times\Bbb Z\,\;,\;\;r\;\;\text{a prime}$ ?

Note: I'm assuming $\,\Bbb Z_r=\Bbb Z/r\Bbb Z\,$

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ has an element of order $p$, for example $(1,0)$, while no element of  $\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$ has this order if $p,q$ are coprime.